# possible to create a file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to create a text file in local storage?

I tried lost of time but l could not do create a file using in jQuery, JavaScript please help me and don't download/save a file in client side only save and replace server side.

Comment: What's you want ? You want to create the file at the `client side` or at the `server side` ?

Comment: to create/edit  is not posibile with javascript alone

Comment: i want to create a file in server side

Comment: At server which language you use? So you have to code in both side.

Comment: yeah i'm using only scripting language like javascript,jquery

Comment: _"how to create a text file in local storage"_ , _"and don't download/save a file in client side only save and replace server side"_ Is requirement to store file in `localStorage` or send file to server?

Comment: The question is too ambiguous. Please be specific about what you are asking. downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *FileSystemObject*.it is IE only.

```js
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var f1 = fso.createtextfile("C:\\myjstest.txt",true);
```

Comment: hi Isv i try this code but i have one error for this :Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined

Comment: It just for IE browser.

Comment: it's not creating same IE browser

Comment: Write file in local drive is not safe.This solution is not a reasonable one for most situations.You should change you browser's security setting or copy the code samples above, and paste them into file on your local drive to work.

Comment: but i'm only using chrome and Mozilla what i do?

Comment: Never possible,unless you develop a plug-in to do that.Can you describe why you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives available for creating files, including `.txt` files, in `javascript`. One of the simplest approache to create a `.txt` file would be to create a `data URI`.

To save file locally you can use `<teatarea>` element to input text content, at click of `<button>` element set `<a>` element `href` to `data URI` where text content is `.value` of `<textarea>` element. If `download` attribute available at `a` element, you can also set the name of the created file, else set `MIME` type of `data URI` to `"application/octet-stream"`

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var file = "data:text/plain," + textarea.value;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    if (a.download === "") {
      a.download = "file-" + new Date().getTime();
    } else {
      file = file.replace(/text\/plain(?=,)/, "application/octet-stream");
    }
    a.href = file;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.onclick = function() {
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
    a.click();
});
```

```html
<textarea>
</textarea>
<br>
<button>save file</button>
```

Comment: hi guest271314  how it's possible send your code for file creation in text using javascript

Comment: _"how it's possible send your code for file creation in text using javscript"_ Send where? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @vallavijay Are you trying to create a text file and save file to local filesystem?

Comment: this file downloading in client side i want only save/replace file in server side

Comment: Can you include server-side process at Question? Are you using `php`, `nodejs`, server-side?